# get data from a smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, eosjs

I am a bit out of my depth here but I'm trying hard to keep up. I'm trying to call a method from a smart contract on EOS. That's the [Bancor Smart Contract](https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts_eos/blob/master/contracts/eos/BancorConverter/BancorConverter.hpp) I'm interested in in particular.

Just for testing purposes, I'd like to call that method => `quick_convert` but I must admit the online doc is quite confusing so if anyone can help me with that I would deeply appreciate it.

As a side question, I'm trying to interact with a smart contract from NodeJS (through the EOS JS driver) so a tailored example in my case would be even more awesome :p

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Before you can call the Bancor Smart Contract, it needs to be deployed to an EOS chain that is publicly accessible over Http. You can either track down the location of Bancor's already deployed contracts, which may, or may not exist. Or, you can deploy your own copy to a local development network, or a test net.

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for your response... I know that the contract is live as there is a [functioning production website](https://eos.bancor.network/) but I cannot figure where and how the contract is being called. I could deploy it locally or on a testnet but that's not my goal, my goal is to be able to interact with a production contract to see how that work (although I could also test that on a testnet indeed ;-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `quick_convert` function is private, so you are not able to call it from outside.

Generally, if you want to call some smart contract from nodejs, you could use `eosjs` to call some exposed `action`.

Comment: Ok I get it, sorry about the newbie question, it makes sense now, thanks for the answers ;-)